# Help finding the most general power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following questions in my differential equations course:

`Find the most general series (with two arbitrary constants) satisfying the differential equation` $f''(x) + f(x) = 0$.

`Find a power series satisfying the differential equation` $xf''(x) + f'(x) + xf(x) = 0$ `with the intial condition` $f(0) = 1$ `hint - leave your answers in sigma notation`

Can the answerer show step-by-step the solution, this way I can understand the necessary steps to derive the answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer is almost in the question. Let $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i$$ $$f'(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty i a_i x^{i-1}$$ $$f''(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty i(i-1) a_i x^{i-2}$$ so the first equation write
$$f''(x)+f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty i(i-1) a_i x^{i-2}+\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i=0$$ The coefficient for each power of $x$ must be equal to $0$ so, for degree $n$ (which is a particular given value of the $i$'s),$$(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+a_n=0$$ For sure, because of $f''(x)$, you cannot define $a_0$ and $a_1$ which will stay your free constants.

I hope you understand the procedure and that you will successfully continue.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: It is amazing. I changed for $i$ to $n$ at the last minute, wanting to mean than $n$ was a particular value of $i$. Thanks for pointing. Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here I will answer your first question. After studying that you can answer for second one your-self
Let $$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n+a_{n+1}x^{n+1}+...$$ 
$$f'(x)=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+...+(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n+(n+2)a_{n+2}x^{n+1}...$$
$$f''(x)=2a_2+3.2a_3x+4.3a_4x^2+...+(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n+(n+3)(n+2)a_{n+3}x^{n+1}...$$
It is given that $f''(x)+f(x)=0.$ Since $1,x,x^2,x^3,...,x^n,...$ are linearly independent comparing the coefficient of $x^n$ in $f''+f$ we can obtain that  $$a_n+(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}=0$$
$$\dfrac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}=\dfrac{-1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$
Terefore, $$a_{2n}=\dfrac{(-1)^na_0}{(2n)!}$$
and
$$a_{2n+1}=\dfrac{(-1)^na_1}{(2n+1)!}$$
If you are familiar with Taylor series representations of $ \sin$ and $ \cos$ you can obtain your solution interms of them.